# android studio 3.6.1 debug cannot find local variable

Tags: java, android, android-studio, debugging, kotlin

Android studio 3.6.1 showing no local variable while debugging, please help me to get out of this.

[no debug local variable screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6Or1.jpg)

My Environment:-

```
Android Studio = 3.6.1 ( with kotlin )
Gradle = 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip
```

Answer (score -3):

Looks like your local variable not used anywhere in code and cleared in build time (Optimization when all unused resources or code filtered and not get into final build).
You can log it for example. So it will be persisted.